# setContentView not working

Tags: android

i have file name TabGroupActivity.java which contains the below function as

```
  public void startChildActivity(String Id, Intent intent) {     
          try{
              Window window = getLocalActivityManager().startActivity(Id,intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP));
              if (window != null) {
                  System.out.println("Start Account page.....");
                  Global.mIdList.add(Id);
                  setContentView(window.getDecorView());

              }   
            } catch(Exception ex){ 
                System.out.println("Start Account page....."+ex.getMessage());
          }

      }
```

This is called from various files, when this is called as below it works.

```
    file name e.java 

    Global.eInsObject = this;
            Global.eIns = new Intent(this,myAccount.class);
            startChildActivity("myAccount",Global.eIns);
```

This works perfectly fine but when i call the below was it doesnt give any error but also doesnt show new view or anything,.

file name :- Home.java

```
System.out.println("Global.eInsObject is" +Global.eInsObject);
                                    System.out.println("Global.eIns is" +Global.eIns);

                                    TabGroupActivity parentActivityE = (TabGroupActivity) Global.eInsObject;
                                    //System.out.println("parentActivityE is "+parentActivityE);
                                    parentActivityE.startChildActivity("myAccount", Global.eIns);
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with the whole Window and DecorView? Are you trying to simple start a new activity? Or something a lot more complex?!

Please explain what you are trying to achieve first.

Comment: I have tabs (for ex :- a, b, c and d )on the top of my application which is controlled my tabGroupAcitivity.java now i have a menu in the bottom, onclick of menu button on device  i get a menu consisting of same (a,b,c) on click of this i need to navigate in the same tab and make that tab clickable or show do the same as what the tab click does , if any clarification please let me know. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Does the http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html not address your requirements?

If you want to do anything else (I can only think of one requirement not met by the tagwidget: Tab-switching between views instead of activities), I'd suggest that you take a look at the `ViewFlipper`. The `ViewFlipper` should let you meet all other requirements.

I still don't completely understand why you had to "setContentView(window.getDecorView())".